# How can I overlay an app to an other app with react native

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I would like to create an application that will be overlayed on another application.

The application will have to take screenshots and then analyze the content of these screenshots via OCR.

Is this possible with react native? or in native android?

Comment: Drawing on top of other apps is possible, but requires special permissions.  It's probably possible to do in RN, but would likely be easier in native.

Taking a screenshot of another app-  depends on if the app is marked as secure or not.  If it is, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently available on android, see [android chat head](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20chathead&oq=android%20chathead&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.645j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)